# jQuery script not working when I link script with full url

Tags: javascript, jquery

It works when I use the local jQuery like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
```

But it doesn't when I link it from my server. And I opened the link and verified that the script loads (I am using a dummy domain instead if the real one).

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://domain.tld/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.11.2"></script>
```

This is the script that doesn't work when I link the jQuery the second way:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var scrollSpeed = 110;
    var current = 0;
    var direction = 'h';
        function bgscroll(){
            current -= 1;
            $('div#la-grid').css("backgroundPosition", (direction == 'h') ? current+"px 0" : "0 " + current+"px")
        }
    setInterval(bgscroll, scrollSpeed);
</script>
```

Comment: *doesn't work*? please explain more. What errors do you see ?

Comment: The background is supposed to scroll. it doesn't...dont get any other errors

Comment: @DhirajBodicherla Could it be that the jQuery is being called through a function?

Comment: 2 things I would do is place the code in `$(document).ready()` and make sure that the script is at the end of the page.

Comment: If you visit the jQuery script URL do you see jQuery code?

Comment: @DhirajBodicherla Did that...still doesn't work.

Comment: very less information to figure out the problem. *In general*, it seems to be working fine. http://jsbin.com/zumuve/1/

Comment: @DhirajBodicherla Actually, when I added document ready, it didn't even work with my local script. Btw I checked they are the same identical script...

Comment: @DhirajBodicherla The script came with wordpress. I am trying to use the same one, to avoid loading it twice. Because the page this is for will load in an iframe

Comment: Are you using `https`? You can try including without `http`: 
`<script src="//domain.tld/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.11.2"></script>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wordpress doesn't create the $ shortcut for jQuery. Replace $ with jQuery.

```
var scrollSpeed = 110;
    var current = 0;
    var direction = 'h';
        function bgscroll(){
            current -= 1;
            jQuery('div#la-grid').css("backgroundPosition", (direction == 'h') ? current+"px 0" : "0 " + current+"px")
        }
    setInterval(bgscroll, scrollSpeed);
```

Sources: https://digwp.com/2011/09/using-instead-of-jquery-in-wordpress/